# Python - trying to convert time from utc to cst in api response

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

Below is code I am using to get data from an api. And below that is the response. I am trying to convert `datetime` from UTC to CST and then present the data with that time zone instead. But I am having trouble isolating `datetime`

```
import requests
import json

weather = requests.get('...')
j = json.loads(weather.text)
print (json.dumps(j, indent=2))
```

Response:

```
{
  "metadata": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "datetime": "2022-12-11T05:00:00Z",
      "is_day_time": false,
      "icon_code": 5,
      "weather_text": "Clear with few low clouds and few cirrus",
      "temperature": {
        "value": 45.968,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "feels_like_temperature": {
        "value": 39.092,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "relative_humidity": 56,
      "precipitation": {
        "precipitation_probability": 4,
        "total_precipitation": {
          "value": 0.0,
          "units": "in"
        }
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": {
          "value": 5.144953471725125,
          "units": "mi/h"
        },
        "direction": 25
      },
      "wind_gust": {
        "value": 9.014853256979242,
        "units": "mi/h"
      },
      "pressure": {
        "value": 29.4171829577118,
        "units": "inHg"
      },
      "visibility": {
        "value": 6.835083114610673,
        "units": "mi"
      },
      "dew_point": {
        "value": 31.01,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "cloud_cover": 31
    },
    {
      "datetime": "2022-12-11T06:00:00Z",
      "is_day_time": false,
      "icon_code": 4,
      "weather_text": "Clear with few low clouds",
      "temperature": {
        "value": 45.068,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "feels_like_temperature": {
        "value": 38.066,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "relative_humidity": 56,
      "precipitation": {
        "precipitation_probability": 5,
        "total_precipitation": {
          "value": 0.0,
          "units": "in"
        }
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": {
          "value": 5.167322834645669,
          "units": "mi/h"
        },
        "direction": 27
      },
      "wind_gust": {
        "value": 8.724051539012168,
        "units": "mi/h"
      },
      "pressure": {
        "value": 29.4213171559632,
        "units": "inHg"
      },
      "visibility": {
        "value": 5.592340730136005,
        "units": "mi"
      },
      "dew_point": {
        "value": 30.2,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "cloud_cover": 13
    },
    {
      "datetime": "2022-12-11T07:00:00Z",
      "is_day_time": false,
      "icon_code": 4,
      "weather_text": "Clear with few low clouds",
      "temperature": {
        "value": 44.33,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "feels_like_temperature": {
        "value": 37.364,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "relative_humidity": 56,
      "precipitation": {
        "precipitation_probability": 4,
        "total_precipitation": {
          "value": 0.0,
          "units": "in"
        }
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": {
          "value": 4.988367931281317,
          "units": "mi/h"
        },
        "direction": 28
      },
      "wind_gust": {
        "value": 8.254294917680744,
        "units": "mi/h"
      },
      "pressure": {
        "value": 29.4165923579616,
        "units": "inHg"
      },
      "visibility": {
        "value": 7.456454306848007,
        "units": "mi"
      },
      "dew_point": {
        "value": 29.714,
        "units": "F"
      },
      "cloud_cover": 22
    }
  ],
  "error": null
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming what you mean is that you want to present the data in the current time of the Central Time zone.  As of the date this question was asked, that would be `CST` (Central Standard Time).  At another time it will be `CDT` (Central Daylight Time) based on daylight savings time rules that are followed in the Country/City for the time zone for which you wish to localize the data.  The rules are all nicely kept in the [IANA Timezone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

So the trick is that you pick your Country/City from the Timezone DB that follows the rules as they apply to your current time zone.  For Central Time, `America/Chicago` usually works but YMMV.

There are a lot of ways to do this. This example is inefficiently iterating through the dictionary created by `json.loads` and replacing the time string with a converted string.  The key is using the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library to parse the timestamp string and convert using the proper UTC offset as defined for the time zone in the IANA database.

Hopefully this example has enough pieces you can copy and adapt to your own needs.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil import tz
import json

j = json.loads(weather)

# Loop through each data entry, reformatting the time
for entry in j["data"]:
  if "datetime" in entry.keys():
    parsed_dt = parse(entry["datetime"])
    converted = parsed_dt.astimezone(tz.gettz("America/Chicago"))
    entry["datetime"] = converted.isoformat()

print (json.dumps(j, indent=2))
```

The resulting JSON has `datetime` fields that contain an ISO timestamp for the `CST` time.

```
{
"metadata": null,
"data": [{
        "datetime": "2022-12-10T23:00:00-06:00",
        "is_day_time": false,
        "icon_code": 5,
        "weather_text": "Clear with few low clouds and few cirrus",
        "temperature": {
            "value": 45.968,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "feels_like_temperature": {
            "value": 39.092,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "relative_humidity": 56,
        "precipitation": {
            "precipitation_probability": 4,
            "total_precipitation": {
                "value": 0.0,
                "units": "in"
            }
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": {
                "value": 5.144953471725125,
                "units": "mi/h"
            },
            "direction": 25
        },
        "wind_gust": {
            "value": 9.014853256979242,
            "units": "mi/h"
        },
        "pressure": {
            "value": 29.4171829577118,
            "units": "inHg"
        },
        "visibility": {
            "value": 6.835083114610673,
            "units": "mi"
        },
        "dew_point": {
            "value": 31.01,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "cloud_cover": 31
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2022-12-11T00:00:00-06:00",
        "is_day_time": false,
        "icon_code": 4,
        "weather_text": "Clear with few low clouds",
        "temperature": {
            "value": 45.068,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "feels_like_temperature": {
            "value": 38.066,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "relative_humidity": 56,
        "precipitation": {
            "precipitation_probability": 5,
            "total_precipitation": {
                "value": 0.0,
                "units": "in"
            }
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": {
                "value": 5.167322834645669,
                "units": "mi/h"
            },
            "direction": 27
        },
        "wind_gust": {
            "value": 8.724051539012168,
            "units": "mi/h"
        },
        "pressure": {
            "value": 29.4213171559632,
            "units": "inHg"
        },
        "visibility": {
            "value": 5.592340730136005,
            "units": "mi"
        },
        "dew_point": {
            "value": 30.2,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "cloud_cover": 13
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2022-12-11T01:00:00-06:00",
        "is_day_time": false,
        "icon_code": 4,
        "weather_text": "Clear with few low clouds",
        "temperature": {
            "value": 44.33,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "feels_like_temperature": {
            "value": 37.364,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "relative_humidity": 56,
        "precipitation": {
            "precipitation_probability": 4,
            "total_precipitation": {
                "value": 0.0,
                "units": "in"
            }
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": {
                "value": 4.988367931281317,
                "units": "mi/h"
            },
            "direction": 28
        },
        "wind_gust": {
            "value": 8.254294917680744,
            "units": "mi/h"
        },
        "pressure": {
            "value": 29.4165923579616,
            "units": "inHg"
        },
        "visibility": {
            "value": 7.456454306848007,
            "units": "mi"
        },
        "dew_point": {
            "value": 29.714,
            "units": "F"
        },
        "cloud_cover": 22
    }
],
"error": null
```

}

Comment: CDT and CST are the same time - just diff names. Thanks.

Comment: They are not.  CST is UTC−06:00, CDT is UTC−05:00.  Never been 1 hour early/1 hour late for work/school after the clocks change? Look at this link and observe 1:00am occur twice.  https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=6,100,2643743&h=6&date=11/6/2022%7C3&hf=1

Comment: How does it actually let you just change what `entry["datetime"]` is and display all the data? Like how does this actually work `entry["datetime"] = converted.isoformat()`. I didn't know you could just treat them like that and change their value like that. How does that actually work? What is parse doing? I also don't understand why you did `if "datetime" in entry.keys():`? If there is a response, there will always be a datetime. Wouldn't it makes more sense to just do a try except for a 200 response?

Comment: "They are not. CST is UTC−06:00, CDT is UTC−05:00...?" That link says CDT / CST and says "soon cdt / cst moves back an hour". It doesn't say, 
CDT becomes CST. It says CDT / CST "changes" by an hour. Where as you're saying that when daylight savings time (in your words "clocks change") happens - CST becomes CDT and vice versa in the Spring. Your link is treating  / representing them as a singular time zone that just has an hour shift in Spring / Fall but in the end is the same thing diff names. Which is how a lot of people view it. But that's all really moot.

Comment: JSON represents key/value pairs and arrays, which generically correspond to Python dictionaries and lists.  JSON lib returns a dictionary or list as appropriate for the JSON string. Anything you can do with those types in Python is valid.  An entry in the list in the `data` element of the response can be null or have any structure without more information about the API.  Theoretically `datetime` would always be there, but in practice I've seen API changes break code.  There are even probably a few other defensive checks I didn't include because it is a simple example.